# How to increment score by 1 after each letter found in a hidden word?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, increment

I'm using JavaFX and I would like to increment the score in a Text Field by 1 each time the user guesses a letter from a hidden word. So far, when I start a new game, score shows 0 and the only time my score increments by 1 is when the very first time a letter is found of the hidden word. After that, score stays at 1 no matter how many right guesses. I am stuck there and can't seem to grasp how to code it.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < actualWord.length(); i++) {
    if (actualWord.charAt(i) == letterClicked.charAt(0)) {
        hiddenWordChars[i] = letterClicked.charAt(0);
        letterFound = true;
    }
}

// Update hidden word
findWordTxtField.setText(new String(hiddenWordChars));
wordLabel.setText(new String(hiddenWordChars));

// If letter not in hidden word
if (!letterFound) {
    lifeRemaining--;
    drawBodyParts();
} else if (letterFound) {
    // +1 when letter is found (only first time)
    scoreTxtField.setText(Integer.toString(scoreInt));
}

// All letters found
if (!new String(hiddenWordChars).contains("_")) {
    wordLabel.setText("Congratulations! You found the word.");
}
```

I am stuck there and can't seem to grasp how to code it. I also have

```
String score = "1";
int scoreInt = Integer.parseInt(score);
```

Comment: I don't see anything updating the score. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: Sorry, then I'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: It would help if the code sample were a complete method. We can, for example, reasonably guess `actualWord` is a `String`, but we shouldn't have to guess. The part of the code where it is declared should be shown. Also, it may be necessary to include code for methods invoked by the one you are having trouble with. For all we know, the problem is in part of the code you didn't show. As a previous comment said, please read the "Minimal Reproducible Example" page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have **not** provided a reproducible example it is hard to truly help, but it looks like you never increment `scoreInt`.

Additionally, you need to add a check for a previously guessed letter, otherwise they could select **c** multiple times for the word **cela** and increment the score.

This extra condition `hiddenWordChars[i] == '_'` fixes that.

```java
int scoreInt = 0;

// When a letter is clicked or guessed
boolean letterFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < actualWord.length(); i++) {
    if (actualWord.charAt(i) == letterClicked.charAt(0) && hiddenWordChars[i] == '_') {
        hiddenWordChars[i] = letterClicked.charAt(0);
        scoreInt++; // Increment the score here
        letterFound = true;
    }
}

// Update hidden word
findWordTxtField.setText(new String(hiddenWordChars));
wordLabel.setText(new String(hiddenWordChars));

// If letter not in hidden word
if (!letterFound) {
    lifeRemaining--;
    drawBodyParts();
} else {
    scoreTxtField.setText(Integer.toString(scoreInt)); // Update score every time
}

// All letters found
if (!new String(hiddenWordChars).contains("_")) {
    wordLabel.setText("Congratulations! You found the word.");
}
```